# How does Firefox process history to show in the location bar's small black down arrow popup?

Tags: algorithm, firefox, browser-history

There's a nice feature in Firefox's awesome bar. It displays your most popular sites in a dropdown list when clicking on a small black down arrow icon on the right side of bar.

There's also a Google Chrome extension which does almost the same but in a less usable way:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/logbmehmiacemkimbpcbjgaikobdndah

I want to optimize this extension a little so the results are like in Firefox. The main difference between Chrome's extension and Firefox's feature is that an extension doesn't process the urls to display shorter path versions. Firefox reduces urls and I often can see just domains without specified paths. However urls like twitter.com/username appear with the path part of url.

It would be great to learn the algorithm Firefox uses for that. I think it is dealing with frecencies somehow.

Any tips are welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't really see any reduction being performed, it's always full URLs for me in Firefox 6 (even with the protocol included). And several entries refer to the same domain. Could it be that this was added in a newer Firefox version? I can see something like that in Firefox 8.0a1.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong that it shortens URL. I'm working with the 6 version too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the algorithm is a very simple one:

- If the "path" part of the URL is "/" - remove it. "http://example.com/" is transformed into "http://example.com" while "http://example.com/foo/" stays the same.
- If the URL starts with "http://" - remove that part. "http://example.com" is transformed into "example.com" while "https://example.com" stays the same.

That seems to be it, it's just removing the URL parts that don't carry any information.

**Edit**: This behavior has been introduced in Firefox 7 and is controlled by the `browser.urlbar.trimURLs` preference. Looking at [the source code (function `trimURL`)](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/cbb901789b3b/browser/base/content/utilityOverlay.js#l620) it works pretty much the way I said (with some additional restrictions).

Comment: That's nice you wrote about Firefox 7 feature I didn't know about. Still I'm working with the current release Firefox 6 version and I liked its way of doing things.

Comment: Then please explain what you mean (ideally with a screenshot). In Firefox 6 I always see full URLs. Unless you have an extension installed that modifies the built-in behavior...

Answer (score 0):

That list purely contains url's you have visited using the awesomebar, or typing the url directly. From that list it picks the most popular.

Considering you usually do not type long url's, the list mostly contain short one's. I myself have 10 short and 2 long url's.